# Line: 6, Column: 1 : CPU time limit exceeded

Tags: apex

```
List<Integer> intList = new List<Integer>();
intList.add(11);
intList.add(12);
intList.add(13);
intList.add(14);
while(intList.iterator().hasNext()){

}
```

why is the CPU time limit exceeding here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For two reasons !

For the first, just see [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28871/iterable-hasnext-and-next)

Each time the loop goes on, a new instance of iterator of your list is created. So you basically ask "Hey iterator1, do you have an item ?". Ten loops later "hey Iterator11, do you have an item ?".

Secondly, you don't update the pointer of your iterator. Which is done with the instruction below.

```
myIterator.next();
```

It prevents from looping indefinitely. And it allows to do instructions on different parts on your iterator's items !

What you want to do to avoid that

```
List<Integer> intList = new List<Integer>();
intList.add(11);
...
Iterator<Integer> intIterator = intList.iterator();

while(intIterator.hasNext()){
    intIterator.next(); // to make sure you have the first element of the iterator
    //some instructions here to test
    //end of loop

}
```

This way for each loop the pointer is updated until it reaches the end of your iterator and thus no CPU time limit.

Comment: See the iterator doc [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_iterable.htm)